# C# Single bool for multiple options

Tags: c#

Solved
Array of booleans

Likely a simple question, just having an issue figuring it out right now.

Making a yahtzee game, have to use a bool value to describe whether a category is open or closed.

So if the person gets 3 sixes, they have the option of putting those 6s in the 6 spot, or the three of a kind, or chance. However, once they put something into one of those spots it should be closed, meaning it could not be used again. The problem is that if i use a bool to describe open or closed, it opens or closes all values. I am supposed to be able to do it with one bool value.

I have tried using the logic that if a value = 0 it is open to being used, meaning no value has been placed yet. Problem is that during the game, if you get a set of dice you cannot use anywhere you have to scratch off a value. So if lets say you get 2,3,2,1,1 as your final set of dice. You have used 1s, 2s, and 3s and chance. You now have to scratch something, so lets say 4. That makes the value of 4s now 0. This means on your next turn 4s = 0 meaning you can now use it again, which I dont want haha.

Yes its for a college project. Have to follow what was asked for, so its supposed to be possible with a single bool.

I want to just make a bunch of bools, but no. I wanted to make an object and get set the bools individually. But not supposed to.

Any ideas?

Comment: show your code..? what do you have thus far also sounds like you can accomplish this using [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: I dont get the q at all. The key is here: "The problem is that if i use a bool to describe open or closed, it opens or closes all values." What does that mean? It's not like we know the game. And also "You now have to scratch something, so lets say 4. That makes the value of 4s now 0". Shouldn't that make value of 4s non-zero? Please edit your question to make things a bit more clear. Also show some code as Dj Kraze says.

Comment: You need to use an array of booleans (or a dictionary of string & boolean) to keep track of the state for each yahtzee combination.

Comment: Simplify your question... this is way too much detail that's unrelated to the problem.

Comment: You would have better chances to get answer if you can show some code. Not everyone knows what yahtzee is.

Comment: You could also considering using -1 as a value for an item that is 'scratched'. This allows you to use your logic `available = (value == 0)` (of course you would have to ignore negative numbers when summing values). There are many ways to approach the problem, but it sounds like you have specific constraints, so there's not a lot we can help with unless you post some sample code.

Comment: Enigmativity i had just implemented that and came back to close this. Thanks though.

Sorry guys, with how much code i have written I didnt think it would be useful to paste it all here. I apologize for not being as clear and concise as i could have.